# Can you move an independent variable to the dependent side of the model?

Tags: biostatistics, dependent-variable

Consider a biochemical reaction f(x1, x2, x3,…), where x1 is substrate and x2, x3, etc… are relevant process variables such as temperature, pH, etc…, and f(x1,x2,x3,…) is the product of the reaction. In any statistical model of f(x1, x2, x3,…) you will find that x1 (substrate) is the most important variable for determining product of the process, by far. This makes sense that the product of a biochemical reaction is primarily driven my the “food” available to the biological organisms.

People in my industry are very interested in yield, defined as product/substrate, and they frequent generate models of the type f(x1, x2, x3,…)/x1 = g(x2,x3,…).

Something feels fundamentally wrong with this. To me it is treating x1 (substrate) as a dependent variable that is itself a function of x2,x3, …. Is this approach legitimate? Please help me understand why or why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense if product/substrate is independent of the level of substrate. For this to be true, it must be the case that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ can be written as $x_1g(x_2,x_3,...)$.

In a regression setting, you could test this a couple of different ways.

You could estimate the linear model 
$$y=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^K \beta_j \ln x_j+\epsilon$$
and test the hypothesis $\beta_1 = 1$. If this hypothesis is true, then the model takes the form $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) = x_1 g(x_2,x_3,...)$ and the reformulation you mention is valid.

You could also estimate the linear model 
$$y/x_1=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^K \beta_j \ln x_j+u$$
or
$$y/x_1=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^K \beta_j x_j+v$$ 
and test the hypothesis $\beta_1 = 0$. Again, if this hypothesis is true, then the model takes the form $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)/x_1 =g(x_2,x_3,...)$ and the reformulation you mention is valid.

Comment: This answer overlooks the more fundamental issue that the *probability models* in the two circumstances differ.  This is buried in the phrases "you can estimate" and overlooked by not including the error terms in the model formulations.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include the error terms in the equations.

Comment: OK, but you need to transform the first equation correctly: the "$\epsilon$" in your three models *are not the same quantities* (nor are the $\beta_j,$ for that matter).